# Is there a way to reference a dynamic date (today, today + 30) within Query Builder?

Tags: outlook

I am trying to create dynamic views in Outlook Tasks based on Due Date. I would like to filter out content that is Due more than 30 days in the future. There are of course some other criteria which seem to work appropriately, but this seems to be particularly tricky.

There are default options for "Due Date" "in the next 7 days" or "in the next week" but those won't meet my needs.

I  have tried some values using the Due Date "on" , but have been so far unsuccessful. In the screenshot below, you can see the canned "Due Date in the next 7 days" display, as well as my attempt with "Due Date on t+30" indicating today + 30 days.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6RWGX.png

I also have access to this SQL version of the filter, and I feel that may be the way to go, but I'm not familiar with the schemas. In this screenshot, you can see that I've included two of my other criteria (Status not Completed, and In Folder does not contain "Personal"), but I've struggled to find information linking these properties in Outlook to the schemas.microsoft.com identifiers.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlh2V.png

It seems I don't not have the reputation to enter screenshots :/

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Or is it a non-programming question?

Comment: I don't have a ton of experience with Outlook coding in general, so this might be a non-coding question.
I tried things like {field:"Start Date"} {Condition:"on or before"} {Value:"today+7"} and it seemed to work.
I had previous tried {Condition:"on"} {Value:"today:today+7"}. However, that did not return tasks from today, although it did return tasks from "today+7".

I struggled to find any documentation for the query builder and the data types for the fields. Given that these seem to compile into SQL, it would be great to understand the fields and the SQL syntax.

Comment: See [Filtering Items Using a Date-time Comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-date-time-comparison) if you decide to do that programmatically.